# Speed up JavaScript/jQuery function

Tags: jquery, function, caching, click, performance

I know that you can cache selectors in jquery/javascript by using “var = $xxx”. I am already doing this with all selectors that will be used more than once…

**Problem:** The javascript animation is slow the first time the visitor activates the function by clicking. Next time they click it works without any hesitation.

Since I don’t know much about JavaScript I wonder if this is because of A or B below:

**A:** This is because the browser caches the selector only when the visitor has “clicked.

**B:** This is because the browser remembers the function/animation.

**Question if A is true:**

Is there a way to cache all selectors before the click functions?

Is there a way to make the browser remember the cached selectors until next time they visit the site?

**Question if B is true:**

Can I somehow cache the functions in JavaScript?

Or can I show how run all the functions when visitors arrive (for example first pop-up a loading div with z-index 10000 and run all functions behind it).

Here’s some example code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var $selector1 = $('#div1'),
$selector2 = $('#div2');

$selector1.click(function(){
$selector2.animate({height:'toggle'},350)
});

});
```

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: The code you posted looks approximately optimal. Whatever makes the animation slow, it is not this code.

Comment: Agreed. You are using ID selectors via '#' selectors (the fastest possible way to get an element), and you're only querying for them once. The issue is in the animation--which is not surprising at all.

Comment: The animate function is apparently slow. What you could do is make an invisible div above div#2 and slideToggle() that one using the jqueryUI. This will do exactly the same. I do not know if the slideToggle functions works any faster though.

Comment: Animation over iframes in IE is slow, and animations with a lot to redraw is also slow in IE. Not sure of the situation, but hope this could help.

Comment: What browser are you testing with?  Do you see a comparable slow-down across Chrome & FF?  (I'm assuming you're using IE, which is a big assumption on my part.)

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. This was just an example code. In the real code there are lots of functions. And as I wrote I experience that the functions only runs smoothly if they already have been clicked (I’m using FF). Will a selector be cached when the page is loaded (before the click) or will it be cached after the click in the above example code? (I’m a noob in JavaScript…)

Comment: Apparently the browser will cache the selector on page load (before the selector is clicked). That leaves me with one question. Will the browser somehow cache/remember the FUNCTIONS?

Comment: wow, nobody answered the question, you should start a bounty to get this answered for sure. I'm still really curious about the answer to this question, did you find the answer?

Answer (score -1):

Hopefully the comments answered your questions about caching in jQuery.  As they said, your code seems good, so its probably an issue with the browser.

If you want to display a loading image while your page loads, you can add an loading image at the beginning of your page:

```
<div id="loader">
<img src="loader.gif" alt="Loading..." />
</div>
```

Then style it using CSS using something like:

```
#loader {
   z-index: 100;
   position: fixed;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: -10px; //(or half the width of your loader image)
}
```

And then add the jQuery function to hide it after your page completes loading:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
   jQuery('#loader').hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I learned that the browser will cache the selector on page load (before the selector is clicked). God to know for a beginner like me. Now I wonder if there is a way to cache the actual function so the browser will remember what to do?

Comment: This answer didn't have anything to do with the question.